# Javascript go through array and find multiple of 3 and give out the number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, modulo

I'd like to look through the array and find the smallest multiple of 3 and either return the value or return false.

I have sorted the array by size of the number and then I use the modulo operator.

This is what I have but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
function firstMultipleOf3(numbers) {
    numbers.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    console.log(numbers);
    for (var i = 0 ; i < firstMultipleOf3.length ; i++) {
        if (firstMultipleOf3[i] % 3 === 0) {
            return [i];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

console.log(firstMultipleOf3([52,98,42,17,33,24])); // 42
console.log(firstMultipleOf3([38,52,34,13,41]));    // false
```

Comment: `[52,98,42,17,33,24].sort().find(n => n % 3 === 0)`

Comment: @dave `Array#sort` with no callback sorts the values in an array as if they were strings `[3,111,3,2,33].sort() // [111, 2, 3, 3, 33]`

Comment: `firstMultipleOf3.length` is equal to `1` (because your function only takes 1 argument, in this case). I think you mean to write `numbers.length` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const numbers = [52, 98, 42, 17, 33, 24];
const find = numbers => numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b).find(n => n % 3 === 0) || false;
const selected = find(numbers)
console.log(selected);
console.log(find([38, 52, 34, 13, 41]));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, you're using the function name instead of the array name (numbers) for your test. Additionally, you're doing this in your if condition.
And, by the example output, you want numbers[i] rather than the index itself.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a generic function and name it.
- Sort the array using `.sort()`
- Use `.find()` to look for a multiple of the passed value in array. This method will return the value which passes the test implemented by callback function or `null`.
- Use `||` to return `false` explicitly in case `.find()` returns `undefined`.

**Demo:**

```js
let findMultipe = (a, m) => a.sort((a, b) => (a - b))
                             .find((n) => (n % m == 0)) || false;

console.log(findMultipe([52, 98, 42, 17, 33, 24], 3));
console.log(findMultipe([38, 52, 34, 13, 41], 3));
```

Comment: Try and avoid `(a < b)`  It will work most the time, but can fail in unexpected ways and make for a hard to debug problem :)..    Just use `(a - b)`

Comment: @Keith Thanks for the input. I'll keep in my mind :)

Comment: note, if you consider `0` to be a multiple of every number, if your array contains a `0`, Mohammad's answer will still return `false`. This is because `0 || false` will be evaluated and `0` is a falsy value.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return false, if *no element* matches. Therefore it needs to be outside the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
  if (numbers[i] % 3 === 0) 
    return numbers[i];

return false;
```

How i would do that:

```
function firstMultipleOf3(numbers) {
  let minimum = false;
  for(const n of numbers) 
    if(!(n % 3) && (!minimum || n < minimum))
       minimum = n;
   return minimum;
}
```